# How to perform SQL-Synchronisation in Multithreaded environment?

Tags: android, ios, sql, multithreading

I'm working in multithread environment application where each of tread can access Local DB to perform their CRUD operation.

I can not go for Async approach because it will not allow other thread to share DB-object, if one tread is already accessing DB.

**Update**
Share [link](https://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html) by pslink help to understand this. *So I got I have SQLite in multithreaded mode, but not serialised.* There I'm using single DB object to access across thread-db-oepration to emulate open-close time, I also using *Prepared statement*.

What should be the best approach to access DB in multithread environment.

Comment: see [this](https://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html) and [this](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=MultiThreading)

Comment: Thanks @pskink for sharing. I understand this, But in my Mutex environment there are very concurrent operation every thread perform & there will be no-surprise if DB-open/close will take more time then operation. What do you suggest !! Please suggest what should be best approach to solve this level of scenario.

Comment: @pskink please check update question, i have added my understanding & query there.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem, and yet... By the moment you required multi-threating and MUTEX access to the DB, there are not many options: use DB locks (I wouldn't recommend at all) or some sort of **orchestrator** that handles request without allowing parallelism, i.e. a DB-Server process with internal queuing.